# Domain access on views

Tags: views, domain-access

I am using domain_access module for multisite. I have two different domains (www.example.com, www.example1.com). If i created a view it will be displayed in both the sites. Now i need to create a view only for the particular domain (www.example.com), It should not be displayed in another domain (www.example1.com).
There is any solution in drupal?

Answer (score 0):

[Domain views](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain_views) module

> Part of the [Domain Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) suite.
>
> Provides Views integration for Domain Access.